# Activate kotlin k2 compiler lint, The option setting 'android.lint.useK2Uast=true' is experimental. The current default is 'false'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried using

```kotlin
android {
  lint {
    useK2Uast = true
  }
}
```

in project level **build.gradle.kts**
to remove error

> The option setting 'android.lint.useK2Uast=true' is experimental.
> The current default is 'false'.

but useK2Uast not present in lint I am using experimental k2 compiler in android studio kotlin 1.9 and

```kotlin
composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
```

> gradle.properties
> `kotlin.experimental.tryK2=true android.lint.useK2Uast=true`

I want to change The current default is 'false' to 'true.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use at least version `8.2.0-alpha12` of the Android Gradle plugin for that property to be visible.

You can read more here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/07/try-k2-compiler-in-your-android-projects.html

Answer (score 1):

> `The option setting 'android.lint.useK2Uast=true' is experimental. The current default is 'false'.`

This should just be a warning, not an error.

To silence the warning, you can add the following to your `gradle.properties` file:

`android.suppressUnsupportedOptionWarnings=android.suppressUnsupportedOptionWarnings,android.lint.useK2Uast`

> I tried using
>
> ```
> android {
>   lint {
>     useK2Uast = true
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> in project level build.gradle.kts to remove error

This DSL does not exist in AGP currently (as of 8.3.0-alpha1). Currently the only way to enable K2 UAST for lint is via the `android.lint.useK2Uast=true` Gradle property as you've done.